# How to make a sliding menu that makes the activity smaller?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I would like to create a sliding menu that pushes the activity to the right and makes it smaller. Something like this:

[image: github - ios]

I found this Floating Drawer for iOS on [github](https://github.com/JVillella/JVFloatingDrawer).

Comment: You got to show an attempt first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Reside Menu` You can get this from [here](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu).